# Best way to deal with installing dependencies?

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking, package-managers

I have a library that I distribute to my customers. I'm exploring the idea of leaving my 3rd party dependencies as dynamically linked dependencies. In this case, deployment for my customers becomes more complicated, as they must install my dependencies before they can use my library. I am a bit new to this, so I have a broad question:

Assuming that all of my customers are on linux, Is an RPM package that simply installs the dependency .so files into system library directories the best route? From what I'm reading about RPMs, this isn't really the way they are meant to be used. I suppose that what I'm looking for is a sort of 'installer' for linux, but maybe such a thing doesn't exist.

Is the best way to just build a package that includes all of the relevant binaries (and licenses, where applicable), and has instructions on how to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

- static linking (if the licenses in play allow it)
- support a range of distros and provide packages for all of them (viability depends on who your customers are) . Easiest option for your customers, most complicated one for you.
- provide an installer that installs your application in a Windows-style self-contained dir structure (eg `/opt/myapp` or `/home/someuser/myapp`). Put the shared libraries in there to and start via a script with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set accordingly. I've seen this option used by Loki games, Adobe Reader, Google Earth and others.

Do not:

- provide a custom installer that will copy your binaries and libraries in the standard directory structure. This may overwrite specific library versions needed for other apps your customer has. It also leaves a terrible mess as the distro's package management won't know about these files.
- provide an `rpm` for everyone. On non-`rpm` distros, this would require your customers to manually convert the package to fit their package management system.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I have a followup: for option 2 (support a range of distros...), what would be an example of a package here? Are we talking about something like a package for a package manager like yum and apt-get?

Comment: @Ben Yes, exactly! For example, you would provide `deb` packages for Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10, `rpm`s for RHEL6 and Fedora, etc... And of course, you'd have to test them :) .